# Opacity of popups in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

I'm not digging the opacity of the popups much (set at 94%, but still). The text underneath clashes to much with the contents of the popups.

I know this is a personal preference, will there be a way to customize your experience in the chat room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this won't be possible. If you'd like to tweak the styles that much, we recommend Greasemonkey or some other method of force-overriding the CSS.

Comment: Fair enough Jeff. Thanks for your quick answer.